# Creating minimum bounding geometry using the convex hull method in R

Tags: r, extents, convex-hull

I would like to create a small enveloppe around a set of polygons that encloses around them. I would like to avoid using the bounding box function (example below) because it would be too big. Rather, I would like to use a convex-hull like algorithm to create a polygon just around the desired polygons. At the very least, an oblique rectangle/diamond would be an improvement to cut out all the corners.

In QGIS, the function is `Minimum bounding geometry` with the geometry type `Convex hull`.

Sample code for image below

```
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
meuse<-as(meuse, "sf")
meuse_poly<-st_buffer(meuse, dist=meuse$elev*15)
meuse_poly$ID<-c(1:nrow(meuse_poly))

plot(st_geometry(meuse_poly))
plot(st_geometry(meuse_poly[which(meuse_poly$landuse=="Bw"),]), add=T, col="red")
plot(st_geometry(st_as_sfc(st_bbox(meuse_poly[which(meuse_poly$landuse=="Bw"),]))), add=T, border="blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a hidden function for calculating the Alpha Convex Hull (Pateiro-Lopez & Rodriguez-Casal 2009) in the development version of `spatialEco`. The reason this function is not in the CRAN release is due to licensing issues in the `alphahull` package.

Please note that this statistic only works for [x,y] data. Polygons are tricky because the bounding geometry is based on the vertices of each polygons, functionally making it based on points ([x,y] vertices). Because of this, if you want an alpha hull, it takes some extra data prep to get points representing the polygon boundaries.

Please install `alphahull` and `remotes` packages from CRAN and then install the development version of `spatialEco` using `remotes::install_github`.

```
remotes::install_github("jeffreyevans/spatialEco")
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(spatialEco)
library(dplyr)
```

Here we add some example data and create your polygons

```
data(meuse)
  sp::coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
  meuse <- as(meuse, "sf")
  meuse_poly <- sf::st_buffer(meuse, dist = meuse$elev*15)
```

Now, we can get [x,y] data from the polygons using the `sf::st_segmentize` function.

```
poly_points <- sf::st_segmentize(meuse_poly, dfMaxLength = 5) %>% 
  sf::st_coordinates() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::select(X, Y) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("X", "Y"))
```

We can then pass the points the the convexHull function

```
a <- spatialEco::convexHull(poly_points,alpha = 100000, sp=FALSE)
 plot(sf::st_geometry(a), cex=1.5, col="red") 
    plot(sf::st_geometry(meuse_poly), add=TRUE)
```

Let's test multiple alpha values to find an optima.

```
  par(mfcol=c(2,2))
    for (a in c(500, 1500, 5000, 100000)) {
    ch <- spatialEco::convexHull(poly_points, alpha = a, sp = FALSE)
      plot(sf::st_geometry(ch), cex=1.5, col="red") 
        plot(sf::st_geometry(meuse_poly), add=TRUE)
         title(paste0("alpha=", a))      
    }
```

**References**

Pateiro-Lopez & Rodriguez-Casal (2009) Generalizing the Convex Hull of a Sample: The R Package alphahull. Journal of Statistical Software 34(5):1-28 http://www.jstatsoft.org/v34/i05/paper